# Closing slash in META-tags disappearing in Next JS

Tags: javascript, next.js

All closing slashes in all meta tags are disappearing while viewing
the source in my browser and it is affecting my SEO.

My Code:

```
import Head from 'next/head'

<Head>
        <meta
          name='description'
          content='Description of the page'
        />
        <meta
          name='facebook-domain-verification'
          content='xxxxxxx90000xxx'
        />
</Head>
```

What I get in dev tools:

```
        <meta
          name='description'
          content='Description of the page'
        >

        <meta
          name='facebook-domain-verification'
          content='xxxxxxx90000xxx'
        >
```

Is there a setting I can change in Next JS to stop this behavior, or any other way to work around it?

Comment: "All closing slashes in all meta tags are disappearing" — They are optional

Comment: "it is affecting my SEO" — This is **extremely** unlikely

Comment: A Facebook employee told me that was the reason why their crawlers couldn't see my verification code

Comment: I can't believe Facebook's parser is that broken. (I can believe their support are that bad through).